# Derivative of Bernstein polynomial

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

I'm trying to obtain the first derivative of Bernstein polynomial 
$$B_k^n={{n}\choose{k}}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$$
My goal is to obtain the derivative as in equation below (Hollig and Horner (2014), p. 12) Approximation and modeling with B-splines): 
$$\frac{d}{d x} b_{k}^{n}(x)=\left(\begin{array}{l}n \\ k\end{array}\right)(1-x)^{n-k-1} x^{k-1}[-(n-k) x+k(1-x)]$$

My effort: 
$$\frac{d}{d x} b_{k}^{n}(x)= {{n}\choose{k}}x^k[n-k-1](1-x)^{n-k-1} + (1-x)^{n-k}k{{n}\choose{k}}x^{k-1}$$

$$={{n}\choose{k}}[[n-k-1]x^k(1-x)^{n-k-1}+k(x^{k-1})(1-x)^{n-k}$$

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a $[n-k]$ and not $[n-k-1]$. Explicitly,
\begin{align*}\frac{d}{dx}B_k^n(x) &= \binom{n}{k} kx^{k-1}(1-x)^{n-k} - (n-k)x^k(1-x)^{n-k-1}\\&=\binom{n}{k}x^{k-1}(1-x)^{n-k-1}[k(1-x) - (n-k)x]\\&=\binom{n}{k}x^{k-1}(1-x)^{n-k-1}[-(n-k)x + k(1-x)]\end{align*}

Comment: I see, thanks, the -1 was not needed.